# Showing the unique maximum of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, maxima-minima

Suppose $f(x) = G^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}G(H(x)\right)+G^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}G(H(1-x)\right) $,

where $x\in[0,1]$ and $G,H$ are strictly increasing, strictly concave functions with $G(0)=H(0)=0$ and $G(1)=H(1)=1$.

If we assume first-order differentiability of $f(.)$, then I believe it is easy to show that the maximiser is some $x>0.5$. However, I am having some difficulties in showing that this is a unique maximiser.

I've drawn a few examples in Mathematica but I cannot seem to construct an example for falsification which supports my intuition that the maximiser is unique, but unfortunately, this lacks any proper rigor.

Any ideas would be most grateful, thanks!

Comment: Possibly helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: I will have a look, thank you! I will try deriving the second order condition again, seems it could be a strong possibility that the maximiser is non-unique after all...